# Ionic and Intent Activity setResult to the caller. How?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I’m using IONIC 3 and my problem is:In android, We are using onActivityResult's getting results from child activity to Caller Activity using onActivityResult's(child activity can use setResult and finish to return a result to Caller Activity) in same way how can we do this in Ionic,Is there any possibility to do this or need to do any other process any advice? Thanks.

### Code:

```
this.navCtrl.push(ChildPage);
```

Comment: No one having idea about this?

Comment: Generally use an angular provider .. Depends on the scenario. You may need to go through angular tutorials. The architecture is a bit different from native android

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

In ionic for this purpose, you can use the ionic modal.

```
let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ChildPage, { param... });
   myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
   myModal.present();
```

check this link for more details. [Ionic Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

Answer (score 0):

The modals in ionic could work fine for this purpose, i suppose.

Use modalCtrl ,

```
import { ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

ProfileModal() {
   let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Child, { Id: ... });
   profileModal.present();
 }
```

[Refer This Space For More](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

Comment: Child page back button not showing if i use ModalController